# Using reference fields as part of entity key with EF 4.1

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I am building my data layer using Entity Framework and I am trying to put reference fields of an entity into the key of that entity.

Using VS2010, .NET 4, EF 4.1, CodeFirst approach.

Given all that info please consider the following code sample:

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public int SetID { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public int SetID { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
} 

public class SalesVolume
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public Product product { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public Customer customer { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public DateTime SalesDate { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

All my data is organized in sets, so Product and Customer entities have setID fields in them.

For SalesVolume, I have references to Product and Customer entities and I want those reference fields to be a part of my composite primary key for SalesVolume.
Quite different from what I am asking, for the code above, EF generated the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SalesVolumes](
    [SalesDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [float] NOT NULL,
    [product_SetID] [int] NULL,
    [product_ProductId] [int] NULL,
    [customer_SetID] [int] NULL,
    [customer_CustomerId] [int] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SalesDate] ASC
)
```

Product and Customer references are placed with two fields each and they are not part of the primary key.

How can I tell EF to generate the SalesVolume table with only one setID field and with PK: (setID, productID, customerID)?

Thanks.

Comment: Try adding the foreign keys in your salesvolumes class and add the key attribute on them. So another property called Customer_CustomerId, Customer_SetID, Product_SetID and Product_ProductID. You can still keep the navigation properties as well.

Answer (score 0):

You actually just need to declare the foreign key relationship:

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public int SetID { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SalesVolume> SalesVolumes {get; set;}
}

public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public int SetID { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SalesVolume> SalesVolumes {get; set;}
} 

public class SalesVolume
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public Product product { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public Customer customer { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public DateTime SalesDate { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```